# LuaJIT 2 optimization guide

Tags: lua, profiling

I'm looking for a good guide on how to optimize Lua code for [LuaJIT 2](http://luajit.org). It should focus on LJ2 specifics, like how to detect which traces are being compiled and which are not, etc.

Any pointers? Collection of links to Lua ML posts would do as an answer (bonus points for summarizing these links here.)

*Update: I've changed the title text from 'profiling' to 'optimization' guide, as this makes more sense.*

Comment: I would also be very glad to have some hints on how to write code that is LuaJIT2 friendly (use closures with local, use metatables, etc).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Update

Mike has recently created and release a wonderful light-weight profiler for LuaJIT, you can find it [here](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/LuaJIT-21-Profiler-released).

### Update

The wiki has gained a few more pages in this area, especially [this one](http://wiki.luajit.org/Numerical-Computing-Performance-Guide), which details some extra stuff not mentioned in the original answer, and is based on a [mailing list post](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/Tuning-numerical-computations-for-LuaJIT-was-Re-ANN-Sci10beta1) by Mike.

---

LuaJIT very recently launched its own [wiki](http://wiki.luajit.org/) and [mailing list](http://luajit.org/list.html), and with such things comes many, many more gems about speeding up code for LuaJIT.

Right now the wiki is pretty thin (but is always looking for people to add to it), however, one great page that was added recently is [a list of NYI functions](http://wiki.luajit.org/NYI). NYI functions cause the JIT to bail out and fallback to the interpreter, so quite obviously one should avoid NYI functions as much as possible on the hotpath, especially in loops.

Some topics of interest from the mailing list:

- [FFI Array Performance](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/FFI-array-performance)
- [An interesting discussion on GC gotcha's](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/more-gc-gotchas)
- [Some more small gotcha's](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/small-gotcha-with-cdata-and-number,4)

And just to repeat whats said further down (cause its just that helpful), `-jv` is the best tool for performance tuning, it should also be your first stop when troubleshooting.

---

### Original Answer

I doubt you'll find much on this actually, mainly cause LJ2 is still in beta, and thus most profiles are done naively as there are no debug hooks for LJ2 specific things like the trace recorder.

On the plus side, the new FFI module does allow direct calls to high resolution timers (or profiling APIs like VTune/CodeAnalyst), you can profile that way, but anything more requires extensions to the LJ2 JIT core, which should not be too hard, as the code is clear and commented.

---

One the trace recorder command line params (taken from [here](http://luajit.org/running.html)):

> The -jv and -jdump commands are extension modules written in Lua. They
>   are mainly used for debugging the JIT compiler itself. For a
>   description of their options and output format, please read the
>   comment block at the start of their source. They can be found in the
>   lib directory of the source distribution or installed under the jit
>   directory. By default this is /usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.0-beta8/jit
>   on POSIX systems.

which means you can use the module code from the commands to form the based of a profiling module for LuaJIT 2.

---

### **Update**

With the update to the question, this becomes a little easier to answer. So lets start from the source, [LuaJIT.org](http://luajit.org):

before manually optimizing code, its always a good idea to check the JIT's optimization tuning resources:

**Compilation**

From the [Running](http://luajit.org/running.html) page we can see all of the options for setting the JIT's parameters, for optimization, we focus on the `-O` option. Immediately Mike tells us that enabling all optimizations has minimal performance impact, so make sure to run in `-O3` (which is now the default), thus the only options here of real value to us are the JIT and Trace thresholds.

These options are very specific to the code your are writing, thus there aren't generic 'optimal settings' apart from the defaults, but needless to say, if your code has many loops, experiment with the loop unrolling and time the execution time (but flush the cache between each run if you are looking for cold start performance).

`-jv` is also useful in helping avoid the know [issues/'fallbacks'](http://luajit.org/status.html) that will cause the JIT to bailout.

The site itself doesn't offer much on how to write better or more optimized code, except for some small tidbits in the [FFI tutorial](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html):

**Function Caching**

Caching of functions is a good performance booster in Lua, but less important to focus on in LuaJIT, as the JIT does most of these optimizations itself, it *is* important to note that caching of FFI C functions is **bad**, it is preferred to cache the namespace that they reside in.

An example from the page:

bad:

```
local funca, funcb = ffi.C.funcb, ffi.C.funcb -- Not helpful!
local function foo(x, n)
  for i=1,n do funcb(funca(x, i), 1) end
end
```

good:

```
local C = ffi.C          -- Instead use this!
local function foo(x, n)
  for i=1,n do C.funcb(C.funca(x, i), 1) end
end
```

**FFI Performance Issues**

the [Status](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#status) section details various constructs & operations that degrade the performance of code (mainly because they aren't compiled, but use the VM fallback instead).

Now we move onto *the* source for all LuaJIT gems, the [Lua mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/):

- [Avoiding C Calls and NYI Lua calls in loops](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-08/msg00106.html): if you want the LJ2 tracer to kick in and give useful feedback, you need to avoid the NYI(not yet implement) functions or C calls where the trace compiler cannot go. So if you have any small C calls that can be imported into lua and are used in loops, import them, at worst they might be '6% slower' than the C compiler implementation, at best its faster.
- [Use linear arrays over ipairs](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-05/msg00007.html): according to Mike, pairs/next will always be slower compared to other methods (there is also a smal tidbit in there about symbol caching for the tracer).
- [Avoid nested loops](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-05/msg00093.html): each nesting level takes an extra pass to trace, and will be slightly less optimized, specifically avoid inner loops with lower iterations.
- [You can use 0-base arrays](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-03/msg00608.html): Mike says here that LuaJIT has no performance penalty for 0 based arrays, unlike standard Lua.
- [Declare locals in the most inner scope as possible](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-02/msg01284.html): there is no real explanation why, but IIRC this has to do with SSA liveliness analysis. also contains some interesting info on how to avoid too many locals (which break's liveliness analysis).
- [Avoid lots of tiny loops](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-02/msg00585.html): this messes up the unrolling heuristics and will slow down the code.

Smaller Tidbits:

- [FFI Tips](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-06/msg00372.html)
- as of beta8 we have bytecode, which can be used to improve cold start performance by removing the parsing step.
- [Some general guidelines](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-03/msg00518.html) on FFI types from Mike
- [Reuse metatables](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-02/msg01102.html) as much as possible
- Speeding up [Lua -> C -> Lua looping](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-02/msg00455.html)
- LJ2 doesn't have Lua's [metatable bugs](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-08/msg00266.html) and avoids proxy tables, to it caches properly.
- update to the Git HEAD when ever possible, it almsot always contains fixes and speed ups.

Profiling tools are available for normal Lua, however, there is one newer project that is officially compatible with LuaJIT (I doubt it'll take any of the LuaJIT features in account though), [luatrace](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ProfilingLuaCode). The Lua wiki also has a page on [optimization tips](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisationTips) for normal Lua, these would need to be tested for their effectiveness under LuaJIT (most of these optimizations are probably performed internally already), however, LuaJIT still uses the default GC, this leaves it as one area where manual optimization gains can still be great (until Mike adds the custom GC he's mentioned doing here and there).

LuaJIT's source contains a few settings for fiddling with the internals of the JIT, however, these would require extensive testing to tune them for one's specific code,
in fact, it might just be better to avoid them entirely, especially for those who
aren't familiar with the internals of the JIT.

Comment: Well, as to "find something on this". I know. But I remember Mike Pall posting some actual info to Lua ML. Also, some people on Lua ML were clearly doing the profiling with LJ2... I kind of expect someone to bite up the bullet and write down a short summary here :-) Sorry for being lazy, but a 200 rep bounty should compensate that somewhat.

Comment: As for trace recorder stuff, there is `-jv -jdump` magical keys which do actually print some useful info.

Comment: @Alexander: IIRC those 'profiles' (http://lua-list.2524044.n2.nabble.com/LuaJIT-2-performance-page-td5854247.html this?) where just scimark benchmarks: http://luajit.org/download/scimark.lua and for the dumping, Mike actualyl says these are for debug purposes (see updated answer)

Comment: No, not only this. I remember discussions on some kind of the math-related software, at least... Also I remember Mike posting some images, taken from his private profiler...

Comment: @Alexander: then your best bet is to email Mike and ask if he is willing to add it to the git repo(if its not hidden in there already), hes pretty good at responding to mails and the mailing list.

Comment: Maybe, but this is not the point of this question. I want to gather existing info in the one place.

Comment: @Alexander: updated my question with the lua-l posts that I found most useful in optimizing lua code and some extra stuff along the way (mainly cause my inbox is not 'one place' :P)

Comment: Thanks! Although your answer has too much on FFI and too little on conventional Lua code to my taste, I'm accepting it.

Comment: @alexander: ffi seems to be the hot topic of the past year when it comes to LuaJIT, I didn't want to go back too far cause then we might encounter things that have changed since the last beta (iirc I went as far back as about the time when 2.0.0.0-beta2)

Comment: "Use linear arrays over ipairs: according to Mike, pairs/next will always be slower compared to other methods"

The link discusses pairs (which is NYI), not ipairs. For regular Lua ipairs is slower than a for loop, but I don't think this would be an issue for Luajit.

Answer (score 7):

Not quite what you're looking for, but I've managed some reverse-engineering of the jit.* tracing facilities. What follows is a bit rough, inaccurate, subject to change and very incomplete.  I'll start making use of it in [luatrace](https://github.com/geoffleyland/luatrace) soon.  These functions are used in several of the -j library files. `dump.lua` is probably a good place to start.

**jit.attach**

You can attach callbacks to a number of compiler events with `jit.attach`.  The callback can be called:

- when a function has been compiled to bytecode ("bc");
- when trace recording starts or stops ("trace");
- as a trace is being recorded ("record");
- or when a trace exits through a side exit ("texit").

Set a callback with `jit.attach(callback, "event")` and clear the same callback with `jit.attach(callback)`

The arguments passed to the callback depend on the event being reported:

- "bc": `callback(func)`. `func` is the function that's just been recorded.
- "trace": `callback(what, tr, func, pc, otr, oex)`

  - `what` is a description of the trace event: "flush", "start", "stop", "abort".  Available for all events.
  - `tr` is the trace number.  Not available for flush.
  - `func` is the function being traced.  Available for start and abort.
  - `pc` is the program counter - the bytecode number of the function being recorded (if this a Lua function).  Available for start and abort.
  - `otr` start: the parent trace number if this is a side trace, abort: abort code (integer)?
  - `oex` start: the exit number for the parent trace, abort: abort reason (string)
- "record": `callback(tr, func, pc, depth)`. The first arguments are the same as for trace start. `depth` is the depth of the inlining of the current bytecode.
- "texit": `callback(tr, ex, ngpr, nfpr)`.

  - `tr` is the trace number as before
  - `ex` is the exit number
  - `ngpr` and `nfpr` are the number of general-purpose and floating point registers that are active at the exit.

**jit.util.funcinfo(func, pc)**

When passed `func` and `pc` from a `jit.attach` callback,
`jit.util.funcinfo` returns a table of information about the function,
much like `debug.getinfo`.

The fields of the table are:

- `linedefined`: as for `debug.getinfo`
- `lastlinedefined`: as for `debug.getinfo`
- `params`: the number of parameters the function takes
- `stackslots`: the number of stack slots the function's local variable use
- `upvalues`: the number of upvalues the function uses
- `bytecodes`: the number of bytecodes it the compiled function
- `gcconsts`: ??
- `nconsts`: ??
- `currentline`: as for `debug.getinfo`
- `isvararg`: if the function is a vararg function`
- `source`: as for `debug.getinfo`
- `loc`: a string describing the source and currentline, like "<source>:<line>"
- `ffid`: the fast function id of the function (if it is one).  In this case only `upvalues` above and `addr` below are valid
- `addr`: the address of the function (if it is not a Lua function).  If it's a C function rather than a fast function, only `upvalues` above is valid

Answer (score 2):

I've used [ProFi](https://gist.github.com/perky/2838755) in the past and found it rather useful!